# How to get headers from response of a server route

Tags: angular, spring-boot, email, http-status-code-302, response-headers

**The process will be like this:**
The user will click a button and they will receive an Email. Within the email, there is a link that will send a `GET` request to the server. The server will then route to a specific path in Angular like `www.myAngularSite/reset`. I have to capture the response headers that come with this route.

I know how to capture response headers when the request is sent by Angular itself but not sure when it's an external request. I have googled a lot about this but none of the solutions applies to my problem.